# rich:menuItem action doesn't redirect without navigation-rule

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

In JSF I want to redirect a page from a dropdown menu. It redirects when I use `faces-config` using `navigation-rule`:

```
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>    
  <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>test</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/pages/design/TestDetails.xhtml</to-view-id>
   <redirect/>
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

But when I try to pass the URL directly, I'm not able to redirect:

```
<rich:menuItem label="someLabel" action="/pages/design/TestDetails.xhtml" />
```

What is the fault in my code?

Comment: Did you try this: `<rich: ...  action="TestDetails?faces-redirect=true" />` ?

Comment: i am able to redirect using navigation but i want it to redirect using action url

Comment: That's an action url .

Comment: i want to forward the page so that i dont want to change the url

Comment: So, just omit the concerning part: `<rich: ... action="TestDetails" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you **should** use `navigation-rule` in JSF's `action` fields (that's what they're for). But if you want to put URL directly then just add `?faces-redirect=true` to it (the equivalent of `<redirect/>` in `navigation-rule`):

```
<rich:menuItem label="someLabel" action="/pages/design/TestDetails.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" />
```

(Notice that you need to put *full path* not just `TestDetails?faces-redirect=true` as @Omar suggested in comments.)

Also: `<from-view-id>*</from-view-id>` can be ommited in rules like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Just new to RichFaces, found out below solution with javascript, seems working:

```
   <rich:dropDownMenu mode="client" label="Navigate">
        <rich:menuItem label="Page - 1" onclick="document.location.href='samplePage.jsf'" />
        <rich:menuItem label="Page - 2" onclick="document.location.href='samplePage2.jsf'" />
    </rich:dropDownMenu>
```